# I need to make a conditional format for many sheets (150<x<200), but it's take too long

Tags: google-apps-script

I need delete all conditional formatting in the sheet and after that create a new rules.

```
var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=NOT(OR($R6=TRUE,$R6=""))')
      .setBackground("#f4cccc")
      .setFontColor("#ff0000")
      .setBold(true)
      .setRanges([blocoPadrao,blocoRev])
      .build();
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=NOT(OR($Q6="Sim",$Q6=""))')
      .setBackground("#f4cccc")
      .setRanges([blocoPadrao,blocoRev])
      .build();

    var rule3 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenTextEqualTo("Loading...")
      .setBackground("#fce5cd")
      .setFontColor("#ff9900")
      .setBold(true)
      .setRanges([formCheck])
      .build();
    var rule4 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenTextEqualTo("Sim")
      .setBackground("#b7e1cd")
      .setFontColor("#34a853")
      .setBold(true)
      .setRanges([formCheck])
      .build() ;
      var rule5 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenTextDoesNotContain("Sim")
      .setBackground("#f4cccc")
      .setFontColor("#ff0000")
      .setBold(true)
      .setRanges([formCheck])
      .build() ;
      var rule6 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND($Q6="Sim",$O6="")')
      .setBackground("#b7e1cd")
      .setRanges([actualPadrao,actualRev])
      .build() ;
```

This rules need apply in this ranges:

('D6:Q17');('D20:Q31');('O6:O17');('O20:O31');('E3');

But when i run this code it's take a long time (more than 30 minutes)...

How this code be faster?

Comment: How many sheets?

Comment: sheets.length have 191 to be exact

Comment: I think that in your situation when Sheets API is used, the process cost will become low. But unfortunately, from your question, your showing script and `when i run this code it's take a long time (more than 30 minutes)`, I cannot correctly imagine your whole script. By this, I cannot propose a sample script using Sheets API. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

I was curious so, using a new spreadsheet I tried to duplicate your conditional format rules.  It runs almost instantly.  There must be something else in your script that is causing it to run slow.

**Code.gs**

```
function myFunction() {
  try {
    let start = new Date();
    start = start.getMilliseconds();
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let blocoPadrao = sheet.getRange("D6:Q17");
    let blocoRev = sheet.getRange("D20:Q31");
    let actualPadrao = sheet.getRange("O6:O17");
    let actualRev = sheet.getRange("O20:O31");
    let formCheck = sheet.getRange("E3");

var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=NOT(OR($R6=TRUE,$R6=""))')
      .setBackground("#f4cccc")
      .setFontColor("#ff0000")
      .setBold(true)
      .setRanges([blocoPadrao,blocoRev])
      .build();
.
.
.

    var rule6 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND($Q6="Sim",$O6="")')
      .setBackground("#b7e1cd")
      .setRanges([actualPadrao,actualRev])
      .build() ;

    var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
    rules.push(rule1,rule2,rule3,rule4,rule5,rule6);
    sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
    let end = new Date();
    end = end.getUTCMilliseconds();
    console.log(end-start);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log (msec)**

```
7:43:55 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:43:55 AM  Info    429
7:43:56 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: First anything thanks for your time!
Soo i forgot a detail this script will run after 4 sheet looks like that: 
for (var i = 4; i < sheets.length; i += 1) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];

Comment: I would expect it to be only 4 times as long. So I think there is still something we are not seeing that is causing the slow performance